# amazon dynamo db model

Tags: database-design, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

planning to switch to amazon dynamo db - http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/ - but having problems with modeling software. what, if anything, is available to have a sort of visual representation of all the 'tables' etc...

or at least what are you using?

my guess at this point is that microsoft excel is closest to the idea, but that is not visual enough.

any ideas at all would be appreciated.

not sure if the question belongs here as it is not directly coding related, but it is much easier to code with a visual representation of the data sets. please forgive me if it was wrong to ask this here.

and, no, it is not a trivial project, so there will be more than just a few different sets.

thnx a lot

edit ** should have mentioned, if it can work with visual studio, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS toolkit for eclipse: http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/ (you see it isn't mentioning anything about dynamodb at this page, but the toolkit do have a great dynamo explorer view).

Answer (score 0):

If the data is bulky you better use amazon dynamodb, but remember dynamodb is NOSQL and it's not relational as far as I know you can't apply any kind of relational logic in dynamo db unlike your mysql.So better clear your requirement and then go for dynamodb.

cheers